# How to add function names to listings package

Tags: listings, matlab

I have some MATLAB code in my tex file, which I am highlighting with the listings package. However, there are some functions, such as "vision.CascadeObjectDetector", "imcomplement", "bwboundaries", "imcrop" that the listings package is not highlighting as functions. Is there any way I can add these functions manually?

Thank you

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal working example (MWE) of your code displaying the problem?

Comment: Use the `emph` and `emphstyle` keys. Example: `\lstset{emph=CascadeObjectDetector,emphstyle=\itshape}`.

Comment: Also, you may be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/matlab-prettifier) package, which sets up `listings` for highlighting MATLAB code; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).